# SQL. Как выбрать не уникальные значения в двух столбцах

Tags: sql

Как выбрать все неуникальные значения из одного столбца понятно

```
SELECT
  name, count(name) AS cnt
FROM users
GROUP BY name
HAVING cnt > 1
```

А как выбрать неуникальные значения из двух столбцов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так например:

```
SELECT t.name, Count(*)
FROM (
SELECT
  name
FROM users
UNION ALL
SELECT
  name1
FROM users) as t
GROUP BY t.name
HAVING  Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: здорово, спасибо, from только забыли)

Comment: @andrew исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Только HAVING неправильно используется же в примере выборки неуникальных значений:

```
SELECT
    name, count(name) AS cnt
FROM users
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(name) > 1
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос